Why can I not load a simple custom firefox extension/addon xpi file? Tried everything
I'm trying to load a simple xpi file I created from this walkthrough below using Android Firefox Nightly.
Things I've done so far
Tried different compression methods to make the zip/xpi
Set xpinstall.signatures.required to false
Set xpinstall.whitelist.required to false
Made sure add-on has an ID
I'm losing my mind here because as far as I know there is no way to know why the xpi/zp file is just showing as grayed out and not installable?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

I have resolved the issue. I have no idea why but I found this...
WORKS - Zip extension contents into test.zip, rename to test.xpi, upload test.xpi to Google drive, read test.xpi from google drive through FireFox.
DOES NOT WORK - Zip extension contents into test.zip, upload to Google drive, rename from test.zip to test.xpi once in Google drive, attempt to load test.xpi from Google drive from firefox.
Renaming from .zip to .xpi once uploaded to Google drive seems to cause issues....odd...
